Having doubts regarding my marriage
Assalamualaikum! I'm a 24-year-old woman, and my parents have arranged a marriage for me with a man who is well-educated, financially stable, and living abroad. Moving abroad aligns with my career goals, but I don't feel attracted to him and there's no spark between us. I want to decline this arrangement but am uncertain. Should I compromise on love when everything else seems ideal? I'm really confused and need advice.

Pray istikharah.

my 5 cents only ...
Psychologists sometimes say marry intellectually and live with love, otherwise if you marry with love you may divorce intellectually. That is to say, love is not for the beginning of the life, where the man and woman should identify each other, and decide based on their pre-defined and hopefully more Akhirah-oriented criteria, but love can blind people of each others' lackings, and people may accept what they think so superior but will find not that much superior after they have married and everything has ended into a marriage which was thought to be a fantasy but appear to be realistic ... In reality a so beautiful garden has its own insects which might bite and prevent you to enjoy every bit of it. So open your eyes and try to get familiar with each other as much as possible. Imagine you are married, can you bear with his habits? his way of looking at life? is his relation with God and Islam acceptable to you or you think he should change according to your wish? do you like his face, and his tone of speaking, or it reminds you of people you don't like very much? Do you like him to be the father of your children? Can you respect him? Can you trust in him and rely on him? How are his friends? Know his friends to know him ... What are his wishes? How does he imagine to be some decades later? Is he lazy or not? and tons of other parameter that you can think about, and should take into account in your criteria list, all graded in priority ...
And last but by no means least, in a Hadeeth a man was told by the holy prophet PBUH if my memories help, that marry your daughter to a good enough believer man, as if he likes your daughter he will be kind with her, and if he dislikes her, he will not oppress her.
so don't take marriage perhaps that easy as it appeared to me you have so ...
